# Using my IEmailSender from Configure() in my Startup.cs file when I receive exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to send an email in my Configure method inside my Startup.cs file, when I receive exceptions.

I'm using [IEmailSender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.services.iemailsender?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and registering it in Startup.cs file like this for the rest of the application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
}
```

But now I want to use it below in the Configure method when I receive an exception, but I'm not sure how to instantiate it and/or use _emailSender, which is a IEmailSender that usually gets injected into the constructor of the class using it, but in this case (Startup.cs) I can't inject it because it hasn't been defined until the ConfigureServices method gets run and adds it as a service.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Seed seeder)
{
     app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => { builder.Run(async context => {
     // where _emailSender is a IEmailSender emailSender   
     await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync("someone@gmail.com", "some subject", "hey an exception error!");
       });
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the service provider from the context and use that to resolve the desired types

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Seed seeder) {

    //...

    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp  => { 
        errorApp.Run(async context => {
            IServiceProvider services = context.RequestServices;
            IEmailSender emailSender = services.GetRequiredService<IEmailSender>();
            UserExceptionOptions options = services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UserExceptionOptions>>().Value;

            await emailSender.SendEmailAsync(options.ExceptionEmailAddress, "some subject", "hey an exception error!");
        });
    });

    //...
}
```

The resolved services can then be used as needed